# Yii CDbCriteria select a field from a related object from another related object

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, orm, yii

Hi I need to create a CDbCriteria query with more complex relations.

Table1 has a relation HAS_ONE to Table2 - let's call it Relation1

Table2 has a relation HAS_ONE to Table3 - let's call it Relation2

Table3 has my desired Field let's call it Field2

$this refers to the class of Table1, where I defined

```
class Table1 extends ActiveRecord {

    public $Field1; // so I can do a search on it

    ...

    public function mySearch()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        //I need to do sth like this:
        $criteria->compare('Relation1.Relation2.Field2',$this->Field1);


        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

But with this I get an error,

Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Relation1.Relation2.Field2' in 'where clause'

Any ideas how to fix it? I do not want to write my own join, I want to do it the ORM way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
class Table1 extends ActiveRecord {

    public $Field1;

    public function mySearch()
    {
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->with = array(
             'relation_to_table2', 
             'relation_to_table2.relation_to_table3'
        );
        $criteria->compare('relation_to_table3.Field2',$this->Field1);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. The relation to Table3 is defined in the table2 model, and the WITH property searches for this relation in Table1, where it does not finds it.

Comment: That one worked :) I didn't know I can write a with condition with a related table in it. Thanks